# Mongo DB: Query for documents currently "live" based on start and end date

Tags: mongodb, date

Documents in my collection include this structure:

```
"time" : { 
         "start" : ISODate("2013-06-10T20:31:48.694Z"), 
         "end" : ISODate("2013-12-11T20:31:48.694Z") 
}
```

Based off the current Time in which the query was made, I need Mongo to return which documents are currently "live" (in that the current time falls between the start and end time of each document).

The only mongo query I can find in this area queries for documents created between two Dates:

```
items.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte:"Mon May 30 18:47:00 +0000 2015",
        $lt: "Sun May 30 20:40:36 +0000 2010"
    }
})
```

What does this "live" query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
var currentTime = new Date();
items.find({
    'time.start': {$lt: currentTime},
    'time.end': {$gt: currentTime}
});
```

Which will find the docs where the current time is between the `start` and `end` times in the doc.

Comment: this does not return the documents that their start time is further in the future

Comment: @DudeSweet Right, because the question is asking for docs where the current time is between the start and end times.